# Divs inside div getting parent's dimendions

Tags: html, css

I have a div inside which there are a couple of divs containing just plain text. but whenever the outer div is given a width, the child div also gets the same size. is there any way to not make this occur so that the child divs get covered for only the text inside it, while the outer div can have any size?

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:inline-block`

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="text">text1</div>
    <br />
    <div class="text">text some text</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.text{display:inline-block;}
```

[Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/jje8z/)